# Xcode error: "An app ID with identifier 'com.xxx.xxx' is not available."

Tags: ios, app-store

I've had a game on the Apple app store (iOS) for a year. I want to update it today, but I get this error message from Xcode:

[image]

I don't want to change the Bundle ID string since my app on the app store already is register under this name.

Here's what my account looks like:
[image]

I've tried removing my old certificates from Key Chain, as well as revoking profiles from the Member Center website, with no success so far. Any idea what I should do?

Comment: You have no provisioning profiles. You can't proceed until you have some. At the very least use the Member Center to make sure this app is registered there and to get yourself provisioning profiles for it.

Comment: Isn't Xcode supposed to download them? It's when I try and "fix" this automatically within Xcode than I get the error message.

Comment: It can only download them if they exist. If you click Download All and nothing happens, you're going to have to deal with this from the Member Center, I think.

Comment: Did you renew your Developer Membership since last year? I presume you did but it can't hurt to make sure. :) Also, did you download the new WWDR Intermediate Certificate? It expired a couple of months ago and invalidated everything.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't know about the WWDR Intermediate Certificate, I'll check... Thanks!

Comment: Ok, this error only appears on my work computer. My laptop runs and archives the app correctly. This is confusing...

Comment: I'm suggesting that the difference lies in what's in the _keychains_ of the two computers.

Comment: Hi again... :) So now does your keychain have _any_ certificates?

Comment: Also: since your laptop works, do you understand how to export your certificates from it and import them into your work computer?

Comment: Actually, sorry for the confusing turn of events, but my laptop's xcode started throwing the same "name taken" error (without any changes on my part that I can think of)...

Comment: It's almost as if it doesn't know you are you, meaning that you are the owner of this app. Apple did some hanky-panky with Apple IDs recently (it invalidated mine, for example), and I wonder if that has something to do with it. Does the Member Center show this app as registered to you?

Comment: I'm talking about this page: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle Can you log into that page and when you do do you see your app?

Comment: Yes! this is what I see when I log in: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73950/Capture%20d%E2%80%99%C3%A9cran%202016-03-23%20%C3%A0%2013.42.23.png

Comment: Hmmm. But I regard the phrase "Xcode iOS App ID" as highly suspect. That isn't what _my_ member center looks like at all. Try deleting that entry and see if you can create a _real_ app ID entry, manually.

Comment: I get this when I try to delete it (which seems somewhat normal): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73950/Capture%20d%E2%80%99%C3%A9cran%202016-03-23%20%C3%A0%2013.48.21.png

Comment: OK fair enough. Is a distribution certificate for it listed here? https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/production

Comment: No, I nothing's there, should i make one manually?

Comment: Here's what I have after creating one: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73950/Capture%20d%E2%80%99%C3%A9cran%202016-03-23%20%C3%A0%2013.55.37.png

Comment: OK! You see how you had no valid provisioning profile before? They wer all invalid! That was the problem (or at least it's symptomatic of the problem). Now it seems you do have one. If that's an App Store Distribution provisioning profile you should be able to download it and use it to submit to the App Store.

Comment: Ok... So your walkthrough (as well as changing the WWDR Intermediate Certificate as you instructed me earlier) made it work... Thanks so much! Any way to turn this into an answer so you get some reputation credit?

Comment: I'll try! I'm not entirely sure of the details so let me know if I haven't captured it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot has happened over the past year. Either the expiry of the WWDR intermediate certificate (which caused a lot of trauma), or the expiry and renewal of your membership, or both, has probably caused your distribution profiles to go dead. You should be able to fix this by first making sure you've got a current valid WWDR intermediate certificate in your keychain, and then going to the [distribution profiles page](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/production) at the Member Center and creating a new distribution profile.