# An App ID with Identifier ‘com.example.project_name’ is not available.Please enter a different string

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, xcode7.3, app-id

I am using Xcode 7.3 to modify an old iOS application. 
The provisioning profile was invalid on the Developer portal. I have edited and regenerated the provisioning profile. 
The only issue I am having when uploading the application on iTunesConnect is : “ **An App ID with Identifier ‘com.example.project_name’ is not available.Please enter a different string** ”.

I have created a new provisioning profile with this AppID, but I am getting the same issue.

How to solve this issue?

[image: Error When Uploading Application]

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["An App ID with bundle identifier X is not available. Please enter a different string" (Xcode 7.3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36206696/an-app-id-with-bundle-identifier-x-is-not-available-please-enter-a-different-s)

Comment: Have you created production certificate and an App Store provisioning profile including that certificate?

Comment: Also, please specify where are you specifying the App ID?

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick - The production certificate was already created in the past. I have tried to create a new provisioning profile including that certificate but still not working.

Comment: @S.D: Can you try creating the certificate again and then generate the app store provisioning profile with that.

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick - I've tried, it's not working.

Comment: @S.D: Ok!! Can you tell us where are you specifying the App ID. I mean which place in your project settings?

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick - General > Identity > Bundle Identifier.

Comment: @S.D: Please make sure the Bundle Identifier in Info tab points to "$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)". Also, please ensure that  "Product Bundle Identifier" under Packaging setting in Build settings tab is the same as what you mentioned in general --> identity tab.

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick - I did it as you said, but I'm getting the following warning in General > Identity : **No matching provisioning profile found. Your build setting specify a provisioning profile with the UUID " ",however, no such provisioning profile was found.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116961/discussion-between-s-d-and-rashmi-ranjan-mallick).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An App ID with Identifier 'com.example.app.extention' is not available. Please enter a different string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346717/an-app-id-with-identifier-com-example-app-extention-is-not-available-please-e)

Answer (score -2):

From the looks of it, there is no appId on developer account with the identifier that you have given in your info.plist .

Comment: The AppID exist on the developer account.