# Cannot create an App ID with matching Bundle ID in Xcode project for first release using Xcode 8.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-id, bundle-identifier

I am trying to create an App ID for my first release. I have a new company developer account. 
I get the error message *'An App ID with Identifier '' is not available. Please enter a different string'* when trying to create the App ID.

This happens when:

I type the name of my app in the App ID Description field and I type the matching Bundle ID from my Xcode project (**com.MyCompany.MyProductName**) in the App ID Suffix field but I get the error and cannot continue.

However, If I type in, say, **'com.MyCompany.MyProductNameVersion1'**, which is different from the Bundle ID in my Xcode project, then I don't get the error and am able to continue??

To my knowledge, I need to enter the same Bundle ID as in my Xcode project but its not working as advised.

Been stuck on this for a few days, reading and trying all I possibly can, I cannot find a solution and cannot proceed.

Any help is appreciated

UPDATE:  In the Accounts section of Xcode > Preferences, I have two entries under 'Team' : the first is my name and (Personal Team) and under 'Role' it says 'User'... the second is my company name and under 'Role' it says 'Agent'..  I also thought this screenshot may be useful. It shows the signing section of the General tab when the Team field is set to my company name: [image]

Comment: please look to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36211262/5251783

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["An App ID with bundle identifier X is not available. Please enter a different string" (Xcode 7.3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36206696/an-app-id-with-bundle-identifier-x-is-not-available-please-enter-a-different-s)

Comment: @Hosny Thanks but this does not help me at all sir..? I've gone through all these threads already

Comment: @Pushkraj Thanks but same as above

Comment: @Hosny I have included an update with screenshot

Comment: ok try to uncheck Automatically manage signing and then create provisioning profile for this AppId And download it double click on it and run

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete an App ID associated with a Personal Team?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552441/how-to-delete-an-app-id-associated-with-a-personal-team)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this sorted. @Beninho85 pointed me in the right direction but the info in this thread was the answer I needed: [How to manage Personal Team info on Apple Developer website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552441/how-to-manage-personal-team-info-on-apple-developer-website)
I had a two teams in my developer account. One was a previous Personal Team before I joined Apple Developer as a 'company'. This Personal Team had created App ID's for development provisioning profiles which were conflicting with identically named App ID's I wanted to create for distribution profiles using my company name. Identically named App ID's cannot be generated within the portal. Only Apple can delete personal Team accounts already registered with them. I had them delete the personal team and App ID's.

Answer (score 1):

You have the answer in your question.
The bundleId must be unique for each application. So if you created this bundleId on another developer account, you can't use it anymore. Delete the previous one or create a new one.

Comment: I am confused about your answer? Everything I have read says to enter the same Bundle ID(identical to the Bundle Identifier in my Xcode project) into the App ID suffix section of the App ID form. What am I missing?  In the Accounts section of Xcode > Preferences, I have two entries under 'Team' : the first is my name and (Personal Team)  and under 'Role' it says 'User'...  the second is my company name and under 'Role' it says 'Agent'..  I'm really confused, whats going on.. I've read the docs and all in this forum relating to this error but I can't figure it out??

Comment: You need to have the same bundle ID between your xCode and your developer account to make it match! But as soon as you have two different developer accounts, you will have two different bundle identifiers. The solution for you is too remove your app from your personal team inside your developer account. After that you will be able to create the app with your bundle Id

Comment: The error you are showing is different and is related to the fact you have no provisioning profile. Maybe you should watch a full tutorial about Apple Certificates and signing

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowing Xcode to "Automatically" manage signing, and you don't see your App ID on the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles web portal, try enabling any capability (i.e. the Siri capability) which will force Xcode to regenerate a provisioning profile (and register the App ID with iTC).

Verify that a new provisioning profile has been created by going to Targets > [Target Name] > General. Next to Provisioning Profile, tap the information button and verify that the Created date is today. Once you see your App ID registered in the portal, you can disable the previously enabled capability.