# How to delete app id created by Xcode 8 automatically managed signing?

Tags: xcode, app-store, code-signing, app-id

I got an issue today while submitting the app to app store. While developing the application using automatic signing it created development certificates and profiles but when i opened the developer account i can't find the certificates and developer profiles and the id was created in wildcard app id but i need it in explicit app id.

And when i try to create an app id with the bundle identifier it shows an alert

There were errors in the data supplied. Please correct and re-submit.
An App ID with Identifier 'com.ngagroupinc.dealsweb' is not available. Please enter a different string.
It shows this message how to create an app id with identifier 'com.ngagroupinc.dealsweb' .

Can anyone please help me out with this problem.

Thankyou.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete an App ID associated with a Personal Team?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552441/how-to-delete-an-app-id-associated-with-a-personal-team)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To delete the App ID created by xcode we have to contact the apple support team to delete the app id. Because they were created in free account virtually. They won't appear in the developers account.So in order to delete the virtually created App id's only apple technical team can do it.

Links that i got answer from:
1. [Cannot create an App ID with matching Bundle ID in Xcode project for first release using Xcode 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41445842/cannot-create-an-app-id-with-matching-bundle-id-in-xcode-project-for-first-relea)
2.[How to manage Personal Team info on Apple Developer website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552441/how-to-manage-personal-team-info-on-apple-developer-website)